# Why can't I Implement Streams functionality in my JAVA project?

Tags: java, functional-programming, compiler-warnings, java-stream, local-variables

I'm a beginner of JAVA programming.
Recently, I tried to use the `map` & `filter` functionality of `Stream`s like the following code shows.

```
    List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("abc", "", "bcd", "", "defg", "jk");
    long count = strList.stream().filter(x -> x.isEmpty()).count();
    System.out.printf("List %s has %d empty strings %n", strList, count);
```

However, the compiler always complains that I need to "Create local variable x".

Maybe I lose some basic steps that is too easy to find any related discussions on Google.

My JAVA compiler version is J2SE 1.5, and I import java.util.stream.* to my file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stream`s and lambda expressions are Java 8 functionality. Upgrade your compiler.

Comment: I can only see version 1.3~1.7 from my properties->Java compiler? how can I find JAVA 8? I think I'm looking for the wrong direction

Comment: Open a command line and type `java -version` and tell us the output

Comment: @林鼎棋 You should download Java 8 SDK as well as an IDE that supports it.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: @林鼎棋 In that case, you just need to upgrade your IDE. For example, if you are using Eclipse, download he latest version.

Comment: @林鼎棋 In the mean time, you can compile your code from the command prompt using `javac`.

Comment: Then you already have Java 8. Go to the Preferences, type `jre` in the search bar, choose `Intalled JREs` and select the path of you JDK8

Comment: I find "Installed JREs" and choose the SDK8 then finished, but the situation didn't change, should I do something else? or how can I know that I add the SDK8 correctly, thanks!

Comment: @林鼎棋 It looks like you are using Eclipse. Which version of Eclipse is it?

Comment: I fix it! thanks everybody! @Eran Yes! it's the version of my Eclipse that cause the problem. Thanks again!